# React: No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type N

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React component, I'm trying to access a property from my component state by key  but I'm getting a warning from my editor:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Item'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Item'.

```
const [form, setForm] = useState<Item | null>(null);


type ItemType = {
  key: string,
  value: string,
  size: string[]
}

const items: ItemType[] = [
  {
    key: 'my_key_1',
    value: 'my_value_1',
    size: ['S', 'M']
  },
  {
    key: 'my_key_2',
    value: 'my_value_2',
    size: ['S']
  },
  {
    key: 'my_key_3',
    value: 'my_value_3',
    size: ['S', 'L']
  },
];

items.forEach(item => {

  // this line will give me a warning, 
  // but if I pass a string directly form?.['my_key_2'] it will not complain about it
  console.log(form?.[item.key]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to access 'form' as if it's an associative array, but it's not. It's just an array of objects. If you want to access the data via 'key' you'd need to alter the code like this:

```
type ItemType = {
  key: string,
  value: string,
  size: string[]
}

interface ItemTypeArray {
  [key: string]: ItemType
}


const YouComponent = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState<ItemTypeArray>()

  const items: ItemTypeArray = {
    "my_key_1": {
      key: 'my_key_1',
      value: 'my_value_1',
      size: ['S', 'M']
    },
    'my_key_2': {
      key: 'my_key_2',
      value: 'my_value_2',
      size: ['S']
    },
    'my_key_3': {
      key: 'my_key_3',
      value: 'my_value_3',
      size: ['S', 'L']
    }
  }

  Object.keys(items).forEach(key => {
    console.log(form?.[key])
  })
```

EDIT:
The line with the error/warning was attempting to access `form[key]` but form is just an array of objects - and those objects contain the `key` you want. So, you need to change your data structure or access it a different way. e.g. with your original data structure you can 'find' the item with the key you want like this:

```
const keyToFind = item.key
const foundItem = form.find(({key})=> key === keyToFind)
console.log(foundItem)
```

Comment: but `form` of my useState will have a different type ` type Item = {my_key_1: string, my_key_2: string, my_key_3: string }`

Comment: form and items are just an array of objects, and those objects have a key property. I've updated answer with a few more details.